# Rspec, shoulda, validate_uniqueness_of with scope and wrong error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec, shoulda

I have following Rspec test:

```
describe Productlimit do

  before(:each) do 
    @productlimit = Factory.create(:productlimit, :user => Factory.create(:user))
  end

  subject { @productlimit }

  ...

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:price_cents).scoped_to(:direction_down, :currency, :market_id, :user_id) }
  ...
end
```

But I get following confusing error:

```
1) Productlimit 
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:price_cents).scoped_to(:direction_down, :currency, :market_id, :user_id) }
       Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when price_cents is set to 9530, got errors: ["direction_down has already been taken (false)"]
```

Can you help me? I don't understand why this isn't working, because the error message seems to be correct?

**EDIT:**

This happens too in other situations as well:

```
# product_spec.rb
...
it { should validate_numericality_of(:price).with_message("price_cents must be greater than 0 (0)") }  

# rake spec:models
Failure/Error: it { should validate_numericality_of(:price).with_message("price_cents must be greater than 0 (0)") }
   Expected errors to include "price_cents must be greater than 0 (0)" when price is set to "abcd", got errors: ["price_cents must be greater than 0 (0)"]
```

Comment: what versions of shoulda/rspec are you using?

Comment: I have shoulda-matchers (1.0.0.beta2), but i tried it with the current 'shoulda' gem as well..

Comment: it seems to me that you are testing something that rails should already be testing. if you have validate_numericality of in your model, why also call it in your tests? that's unnecessary duplication

Comment: if the validation is part of the specification of the behavior, he should be testing it.

Comment: Does the Factory.create call succeed by itself? You might try isolating this test by running it on a Productlist.new(:price_cents => ...) object.

Comment: The factory creation works quite well, no errors or warnings...

Comment: Do you mind adding the Productlimit model code as well, in the question?

Comment: Two things I'd like to point out: (1) Factory.create hits the database, use .build instead so it just creates the object without the record. You can still check validations on non-stored records. (2) Move the factory to a let, so that it's lazy evaluated in the scope of the description/context block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To check validate_uniqueness_of(:field) but for this you should at lease one record in database to check uniquness constrain.
Here is....

```
before do
  @country = FactoryGirl.create(:country, :id =>"a0000007-0000-0000-0000-000000000009",:currency_id => "a0000006-0000-0000-0000-000000000004",:merchant_id => "a0000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",:country_code => 'CAN', :name => 'Canada')
end
```

## To validate uniqueness

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:country_code)}
```

It will work out try it out.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what [Riche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195369/ritchie) has said about uniqueness validation on :direction_down, I would suspect the way your ProductLimit factory generates values for :direction_down. It might not always be generating unique values for all attributes which have the uniqueness validation on them.

Also, one issue I have faced with uniqueness validation is the first object ( the subject in your case) thats is created before the validation check should not have any conflicting values with ones the factory "randomly" generates. To illustrate with a trivial example,

```
Factory(:product_limit, :direction_down => "abc")
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:price_cents).scoped_to(:direction_down) }
```

has the potential to fail **wrongly**, in case the object constructed by the shoulda matcher ends with direction_down set to "abc" when there is a uniqueness validation on :direction_down.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the database_cleaner settings in the sepc_helper?
if not then add

```
gem "database_cleaner"
```

in spec_helper.rb
add the following in the **RSpec.configure** block

```
 config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

 config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
 end

 config.before(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.start
 end

 config.after(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end
```

Also can you post the Factory code? just to have a clearer picture.

I hope this helps.

Also check if there is any uniqueness validation on :direction_down attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ich removed now this specific test and test it myself manually... Tried your solution, but didnt work either..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `test/fixtures/*` and try to manually create object before testing uniqueness (not using Factory). Also, have you tried:

```
    class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

Comment: I test with rspec (no test folder at all) and tried it to save my objects manually, which works. But the test doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't correct for the matcher because it's complaining about the uniqueness of :direction_down when you asked it to test that the uniqueness of :price_cents was valid.

Does the code for your model include a `validates_uniqueness_of :direction_down`? If so, that would explain the message.

Answer (score 0):

The first case (with `validate_uniquess_of`) happened to me after an unexpected crash. A simple `rake db:test:prepare` fixed it.